# Iterate Over All Cells That Are Found in Do Until Loop

Tags: vba, excel, replace

I am attempting to find duplicated values and in a column in excel and put 3 values in the corresponding columns next to the item.  The problem I am struggling with is that my search range is finding the same range over and over again rather than moving on to the next range that's found to contain the string or setting the `replaceValuesRange` to `Nothing`.

I subsequently decided to change the string value to `MainInputSHeet.Cells(loopCounter, 4).Value = findString & " FOUND"` in an attempt to change the value of the string, but I still get stuck in the find loop, which I assume is because the string is still existing within the cell.

Any ideas?  The issue exists in the `Do Until` Loop.  Everything else is working fine

This is what the immediate window looks like iterating through the DoLoop:

```
$D$5
$D$5
$D$5
$D$5
$D$5
$D$5
$D$5
$D$5
$D$5
$D$5
```

**Main code block**

```
Option Explicit
Public Const DIR_SDR_PRODUCT_DEFINITIONS_FILEPATH As String = "U:\Research_Dev Docs\DevFolder\SDR Sheet\SDRProductDefinitionsICE.xlsx"

Public Sub TranslateAndPullProductInformation()

    Dim lastRow As Integer, loopCounter As Integer
    Dim sdrICEDefinitions As Workbook
    Dim DefinitionsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim findString As String, productTypeString As String, marketTypeString As String, contractTypeString As String
    Dim searchRange As Range, findValuesRange As Range, replaceValuesRange As Range

    'Checks file exists in specificed path, assigns workbook name, assigns proper worksheet for information definitions
    If Len(Dir(DIR_SDR_PRODUCT_DEFINITIONS_FILEPATH)) = 0 Then GoTo BAIL_OUT

    Set sdrICEDefinitions = Workbooks.Open(DIR_SDR_PRODUCT_DEFINITIONS_FILEPATH)

    Set DefinitionsSheet = sdrICEDefinitions.Sheets(1)

    Set searchRange = DefinitionsSheet.Range("A:A")

    lastRow = MainInputSheet.Cells(MainInputSheet.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    For loopCounter = 2 To lastRow

        If IsEmpty(MainInputSheet.Cells(loopCounter, 3)) = True Then

            findString = MainInputSheet.Cells(loopCounter, 4).Value

            Set findValuesRange = searchRange.Find(findString)

            Set replaceValuesRange = MainInputSheet.Range(MainInputSheet.Cells(2, 4), MainInputSheet.Cells(lastRow, 4)).Find(findString)

            Do Until replaceValuesRange Is Nothing

                'Product Name
                MainInputSheet.Cells(loopCounter, 1) = findValuesRange.Offset(0, 1).Value

                'Market Type
                MainInputSheet.Cells(loopCounter, 2) = findValuesRange.Offset(0, 2).Value

                'Contract Type
                MainInputSheet.Cells(loopCounter, 3) = findValuesRange.Offset(0, 3).Value

                MainInputSheet.Cells(loopCounter, 4).Value = findString & " FOUND"

                Set replaceValuesRange = MainInputSheet.Range(MainInputSheet.Cells(2, 4), MainInputSheet.Cells(lastRow, 4)).FindNext

                Debug.Print replaceValuesRange.Address

            Loop

        End If

    Next

Exit Sub

BAIL_OUT:

    MsgBox ("ProductDefinitions File not found")

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the value you search occurs in other cell than D5, for example D20?

Comment: @Limak They can, but the problem is that sometimes they do not. The value can occur once in the data range or it can occur a few thousand times.

Comment: But in this specific example? I'm asking if the problem is, that when the `findString` occurs in data i.e. in cells D10, D23 and D34, this `Do Until` loop goes infinitely through this 3 cells, over and over. Or, if it only will go through the first one (D10 in this example).

Comment: @Limak It will only go through the first one over and over again (D10 in this example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that

```
Set replaceValuesRange = MainInputSheet.Range(MainInputSheet.Cells(2, 4), MainInputSheet.Cells(lastRow, 4)).FindNext
```

will start searching from the begging every time. To continue searching (show next occurrence of searched value) you have to use:

```
Set replaceValuesRange = MainInputSheet.Range(MainInputSheet.Cells(2, 4), MainInputSheet.Cells(lastRow, 4)).FindNext(replaceValuesRange)
```

Now the problem is, that the `Do Until` loop will go infinitely, but for every cell with searched value. I am not sure if there is some smarter way to stop the loop, but I just save row number of first found cell to `fstRow` variable, and then change `StopStop` variable for `True` when the loop will find this first cell once more:

```
Dim StopStop As Boolean
Dim fstRow As Long

    StopStop = False
    Set replaceValuesRange = MainInputSheet.Range(MainInputSheet.Cells(2, 4), MainInputSheet.Cells(lastRow, 4)).Find(findString)
    If Not replaceValuesRange Is Nothing Then fstRow = replaceValuesRange.Row
    Do Until replaceValuesRange Is Nothing Or StopStop
        Set replaceValuesRange = MainInputSheet.Range(MainInputSheet.Cells(2, 4), MainInputSheet.Cells(lastRow, 4)).FindNext(replaceValuesRange)
        If replaceValuesRange.Row = fstRow Then StopStop = True
    Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article recently about Find, but it's in Portuguese, I think it won't help you.

In that article I've put an example code, which you can study and understand how it does work:

```
Sub FindTest()

Dim Interval As Range
Dim Value As String
Dim Result As Range
Dim PreviousResult As Range

Set Interval = Range("A1:A1000")
Value = "Pedro*"
Set Result = Intervalo.Find(Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)

If Result Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Value not found"
    Exit Sub
End If

Do
    Debug.Print Result.Value
    Set PreviousResult = Result
    Set Result = Interval.Find(Value, After:=PreviousResult, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
Loop Until Result.Row < PreviousResult.Row

End Sub
```

It is a good idea to read [Find documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to understand each parameter. I hope that it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your problem is that you have set replaceValuesRange as a range object.  You then use the do loop to run until that range is nothing.  The problem is that the range is still an object and will stay an object until you do something else to that variable.  I would change this to another for loop and iterate through the range.

Maybe something like

for i = 2 to lastrow 'your variable range starts at row 2 and goes until the last row.
   code here
next i

Comment: Adam I have that already, but I would rather only have to search the definitions sheet once to satisfy all incidences of that string in the main sheet. Rather than possibly searching for the same string many times in both sheets.

Comment: If that is the case, then you need to add an argument to .findnext.  It has an optional argument of a starting cell.  So in your code, you will need to set a variable to the exact cell you find each instance of the findstring, then use that variable as the argument for findnext.  Example

Comment: Set replaceValuesRange = MainInputSheet.Range(MainInputSheet.Cells(2, 4), MainInputSheet.Cells(lastRow, 4)).FindNext(replaceValuesRange)

Comment: A perfect example of what I am suggesting can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143.aspx

Comment: I tried the solution you listed and i'm still getting stuck in the same cell over and over again.  Unsure why the range is being listed as a single range.